Deriving the equal time anti-commutator of the Dirac fields
I am trying to solve an exercise on deriving the equal-time anti-commutator of the Dirac fields. But I got stuck somewhere and couldn't get the desired result.
I would like to show that
$$
\{\psi(x), \psi(y) \} = \gamma^0 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x} - \vec{y}).
$$
It has been shown in previous exercises that
$$
\{\psi^\pm (x), \overline{\psi}^\mp(y) \} = i(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m) \Delta^\pm (x-y).
$$
The following is what I got:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\{\psi(x), \overline{\psi}(y) \} 
&= \{\psi^+(x), \overline{\psi}^-(y) \} + \{\psi^-(x), \overline{\psi}^+(y) \} \\
&= i(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m) \Delta^+ (x-y) + i(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \Delta^- (x-y) \\
&= i(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m) \int\frac{d\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega(\vec{p})} e^{-ip(x-y)} + i(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m) \ \int\frac{d\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega(\vec{p})} e^{ip(x-y)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
I have no idea how to proceed after this.
The mode expansion of the Dirac fields is given by:
$$
\psi(x) =  \int\frac{d\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega(\vec{p})} a_s(p)u(p,s) e^{-ipx} + b^\dagger_s(p) v(p,s)  e^{ipx}.
$$

Please note that homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer conceptual questions over those just asking for a specific computation. Notice that even if your question is not homework, it may still be homework-like.

The relation you are trying to show is wrong. The equal-time anti-commutation relations for the Dirac field are (see for example Peskin & Schroeder, (3.108) )
\begin{align}
\big\lbrace\psi_a(\textbf{x}),\psi^{\dagger}_b(\textbf{y})\big\rbrace & = \delta_{ab}\delta(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}) \\
\big\lbrace\psi_a(\textbf{x}),\psi_b(\textbf{y})\big\rbrace & = 0\\ \big\lbrace\psi^{\dagger}_a(\textbf{x}),\psi^{\dagger}_b(\textbf{y})\big\rbrace & = 0
\end{align}
Also (anti-)commutation relations in Quantum Field Theory are usually simply imposed (that is what it is meant by cannonical quantization), rather than derived from some other principles.
